# HTML panel and side panels are empty in Firebug

Tags: firebug

When I open Firebug (via <kbd>F12</kbd>) the HTML panel is blank. Where can I find the option to get the HTML node view back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day I just removed Firebug and Firefox from the system and installed them again. I know not the most professional solution, but I could go on with my project :-)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
Firebug Icon Menu > Options > Reset All Firebug Options
```

Reference: [Google Group](http://osdir.com/ml/firebug/2010-04/msg00187.html)

Comment: After googling and googling with no success - this worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem: although my HTML tab was populated with node view, the side-CSS-panel was empty. It turned out it was due a buggy FireBug addon - Friendly Bug. So my advice would be to disable all addons and re-enable them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you have several options:

1. **Disable other add-ons**

   It might be that Firebug is conflicting with another add-on. So you should disable the other add-ons to see whether one of them causes the problem. This can be done manually via the Add-on Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Extensions*) by clicking *Disable* besides every extension or by disabling all extensions at once via Firefox menu > *?* > *Restart with Add-ons Disabled...*.
2. **Reset the current Firefox profile**

   You may want to reset the current Firefox profile, which removes add-ons and sets all preferences back to their default value. This can be done via Firefox menu > *?* > *Troubleshooting information* > *Refresh Firefox*. For more information about that solution please [read the related article on support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings).
3. **Create a new Firefox profile**

   By creating a new Firefox profile you will ensure that no extensions or settings in your default profile have influence on the issue. To create a new profile, you need to run Firefox with the parameter `-p`. To run two instances of Firefox with different profiles, you can additionally use the parameter `-no-remote`. This will then open the profile manager dialog. In there you can create a new profile by clicking the *Create Profile...* button and following the wizard. Once that's done click on *Start Firefox* to start Firefox using the new profile. A more detailed description how to do that [can be found on support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

If your issue persists after you've done the above, then it's probably a bug in Firebug and you should [report it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues).

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug menu at top of the page (click down arrow next to the icon) I have clicked on "Enable All Panels". That works for me.
But I can't find same command in Firebug panel.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a download of an earlier version of Firefox(v.46)in this case. It fixed the issue